# Javascript globalization problem in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, globalization

```
function GetDateInLocalFormat(strDate) {

if (strDate == undefined)
    return ""

var dateVal = new Date(strDate));
if (dateVal == null || isNaN(dateVal)) {    
    return "";
}

    return dateVal.localeFormat(Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

}

I'm using the above function in Javascript display the date in localized format, new Date(strDate) is not working as expected.

Any suggestions to do date globalization in Javascript?

Comment: what's not working as expected? is the value of strDate one that can be used to construct a new Date instance in the problem case?

Comment: Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern look like none-javascript code to me, don't you think you ahve mixed something up here? also you have a ) to much in the line `var dateVal = new Date(strDate));`

Comment: Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern is to get current culture's short date pateern, works with Ajax.

Comment: yes, the problem is new Date(), it'll always return in US date format.

Comment: Never heard it called globalization....

Comment: ok, how do I convert a given date in US format to local format?

Comment: @JJK that's C# not JavaScript. `.localeFormat` is C#

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Globalize](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/39118647/Globalize) library (originating [from Microsoft](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2010/100614-ms-jquery.html), it was promoted as [an official jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-global), and then made available as a simple Javascript library).